# How to lose touch event on parent when a OverlayItem is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a OSM MapView where i can set some markers to pin locations. These markers have a `OnItemGestureListener` with `onItemSingleTapUp` to open a dialog with some infos. The `MapView` have a `OnTouchListener` to make it fullscreen and hide some GUI.

Everything is working just fine, the problem here is that when the `OverlayItem` is clicked the `MapView` `TouchListener` triggers too, and that's not supposed to happen. There is some way to lose this touch on the `MapView` when the marker is clicked? tried a bunch of ways but nothing worked. the mapview touch listener is always called first.

add marker method and the gesture listener:

```
public void addMarker(double latitude, double longitude, Drawable icon, final int posicao, boolean isLocalizacaoUsuario) {
    GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem("", "", center);
    if (posicao >= 0)
        icon = criaMarcadorMapa(posicao, icon);

    overlayItem.setMarker(icon);
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    overlayItemArrayList.add(overlayItem);
    final ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> locationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<>(overlayItemArrayList,
            new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
```

MapView TouchListener:

```
  osm.isClickable();
    osm.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    tempoTouchDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    tempoTouchTotal = System.currentTimeMillis() - tempoTouchDown;
                    controladorInterface(tempoTouchTotal);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Value returned from touch listener is critical for touch propagation. You're returning `false` from map touch listener which means touch is not being consumed so it works "silently" on top of your marker listeners.

Comment: @Pawel But returning true, the OnTouch gets in front of other functionalities, like dragging the map. and the marker stopped working at all..